# how to decode QR_CODE from webcam in c#?

Tags: c#, qr-code, zxing

I am coming to a problem where I need help to decode qr code from webcam in C#.. I am currently use zxing the library in c#. But, for some reason I am kind of stuck and need help to solve this issue properly. Almost all the tutorial code(s) are outdated. So, if anyone help me decode my qr code from my webcam that will will be great. By the way I am using Unity as my front end and C# in backend. Thanks for the kind help. Cheers.

The Json Result:

```
{"name":"Mike"}
```

Here is my code:

```
    public void CheckQrCode()
       {
           var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://PROJECT_URL.firebaseio.com/qrCode/qrCode.json");
           httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
           httpWebRequest.Method = "PUT";

           using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
           {


               try
               {
                   // Instantiate the barcode reader object. 
                   IBarcodeReader barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader();

                   // decode the current frame
                   var result = barcodeReader.Decode(camTexture.GetPixels32(),
                       camTexture.width, camTexture.height);
                   if (result != null)
                   {
                       Debug.Log("Decoded text is from QR Code" + result.Text);
                       SceneManager.LoadScene("Verify");
                       streamWriter.Write(result);

                   }
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   Debug.LogWarning (ex.Message); 

               }



           }

           var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
           using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
           {
               var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

           } 
         }


   }
```

Comment: The result.Text is json.  Can you post the json?

Comment: Yes. Please see updated question with the parsed json.

Comment: @jdweng any luck?

Comment: So you want to get the name "Mike"? If you want something else than you need to put more into the PUT.  See : https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/read-barcodes

Comment: Yes. basically.. I don't need more. and please note if I show  another qr code that returns different name then show that name.

Comment: @jdweng For some reason when I debug and step into this line `if (result != null)` I get `result` that is set to  `null`.

Comment: Do you get results that is null or the QR_CODE that is null?

Comment: the `results` that is null.

Comment: @jdweng any luck?

Comment: If you are getting data from a database use  (result != DBNull.Value)

Comment: so, I did this: `if (result != DBNull.Value)`  is this correct?

Comment: Did DBNull.Value  work?

Comment: Do I need to implement `DBNull.Value` inside my if-block like this: `if (result != DBNull.Value)` ?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: barcodeReader.Decode() gives null as result if it could not decode any barcode inside the image.
Make sure that camTexture.width and camTexture.height containing correct values. I know from other users that they sometimes had issues with that. If possible make a dump of the return value from camTexture.GetPixels32() and convert it to a bitmap image. Look at the image and make sure that it really shows a QR code. Sometimes there are some trouble with webcams, drivers etc.